# Changing Record of Subform in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a form that contains 4 subforms. The first subform gets data based on a selection in a combo box on the main form. The second subform gets data based on the first subform, and the third and fourth subforms get data based on the first.

It's a database contain information on research grants. I want to be able to pull up certain data based on a person's ID (multiple records to a person) or by the title of the grant. Names are working fine, but searching by title is giving me a hard time.

I've tried setting first subform's Record Source with a .RecordSource ="" line, but nothing updates at all when the code runs (the code is in the AfterUpdate event of the combo box containing grant titles). This one has me sort of stuck; I'm not sure if the dependencies among my forms have something to do with it.

Comment: where's dave fenton when you need him?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with less than 4 subforms? Can you clarify what you mean by `giving me a hard time`? Do you mean poor performance, missing data, etc.?

Comment: try to put Msgbox "something" in the AfterUpdate event and see whether this event is triggered or not. I doubt that you have triggered this event

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a Form.Refresh in after you updated the recordsource?